# How to filter data in CDS(powerapps) to restrict unauthorized users

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, common-data-service

I have created a custom entity in common data services(CDS) that streams in data from a survey.

I'll however need to give access to the data to various people. In my dataset, I have a column called community, which should represent which people have access to what data based on the community they've entered the column.

How exactly can I filter the data, after it has streamed in to ensure I only give access to people of a particular community. And yes every community is exclusive, no two people can be in two different communities.

I want to filter by the community, such that those in community A see only A and not B or C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no straight one step OOB configuration to achieve this. Because the row level security depends on the column value ie. community field value of each record.

One way is to create owner teams and add the users to right teams, then the custom entity record has to be owned by respective team - owner team of each custom entity record can be filled/assigned automatically based on the community field value on create using plugin/workflow/Flow.

Most important, in security role for that custom entity - read privilege has to be given only for user level. Assign the security role to Teams.

Comment: Thank you for this, Does creating Teams and Business Units hinder the data filtering? I've created business units of the different community records so far I only have two, however, I fail to link the custom entity to the business units, is there a way to do this, I'm fairly new in CRM/CDS and I can't seem to find a clear explanation online on how to achieve it.

Comment: @Didi to understand read this - http://hamzehzawahreh.blogspot.com/2015/06/the-main-difference-between-business.html. if only the respective BU team will be owning the respective community record, then its easy to assign the record to default BU team and role privilege can be BU level. Better read this for complete understanding - https://www.quantacrm.com/2018/06/27/introduction-crm-security-management-microsoft-dynamics-365-for-sales/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.